# JSON to C#, deserialize property that is either object or array

Tags: c#, json

I have an issue with handling JSON data from an api that I use in my application. The problem is that the JSON contains some properties that are an object when there is an item, and become an array when there are more items. So that's a structure like this:

```
[
  {
     "MyObj": {
            "Foo": "Bar"
        }
  }, 
  {
     "MyObj": [
            {
                "Foo": "Bar1"
            }, 
            {
                "Foo": "Bar2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I've tried several JSON to C# converters, some of them generate a property of type object, the quicktype.io converter generates this:

```
public class Example
    {
        [JsonProperty("MyObj")]
        public MyObjUnion MyObj { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class MyObjElement
    {
        [JsonProperty("Foo")]
        public string Foo { get; set; }
    }

    public struct MyObjUnion
    {
        public MyObjElement MyObjElement;
        public MyObjElement[] MyObjElementArray;

        public static implicit operator MyObjUnion(MyObjElement MyObjElement) => new MyObjUnion { MyObjElement = MyObjElement };
        public static implicit operator MyObjUnion(MyObjElement[] MyObjElementArray) => new MyObjUnion { MyObjElementArray = MyObjElementArray };
    }

 internal class MyObjUnionConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type t) => t == typeof(MyObjUnion) || t == typeof(MyObjUnion?);

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type t, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            switch (reader.TokenType)
            {
                case JsonToken.StartObject:
                    var objectValue = serializer.Deserialize<MyObjElement>(reader);
                    return new MyObjUnion { MyObjElement = objectValue };
                case JsonToken.StartArray:
                    var arrayValue = serializer.Deserialize<MyObjElement[]>(reader);
                    return new MyObjUnion { MyObjElementArray = arrayValue };
            }
            throw new Exception("Cannot unmarshal type MyObjUnion");
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object untypedValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            var value = (MyObjUnion)untypedValue;
            if (value.MyObjElementArray != null)
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, value.MyObjElementArray);
                return;
            }
            if (value.MyObjElement != null)
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, value.MyObjElement);
                return;
            }
            throw new Exception("Cannot marshal type MyObjUnion");
        }

        public static readonly MyObjUnionConverter Singleton = new MyObjUnionConverter();
    }
```

Although this does work correctly, it's still a bit cumbersome because to get the data you always need to check if it's in the `MyObjElement` or `MyObjElementArray` class.
So the question is if there are other, more elegant ways to solve this issue. (Other than changing the API output, which is not mine)

Comment: Put a getter which always returns a new MyObjElement[] filled with MyObjElement or MyObjElementAttay

Comment: If you can control the API data contract, change the response to use an array no matter the number of elements.

Comment: @owairc that's what I'm doing now in code, but it never occurred to me that I can of course also add a property to the generated class to do that. I think that's probably the best solution for this situation

Comment: @CosminSontu as I mentioned in the last line, changing the output of the API is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the data structure before hand, I would create a custom data model for the Json file and then deserialise it like so:

```
            CurrencyExchangeRates deserialisedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CurrencyExchangeRates>(savedData);

            foreach (CurrentRate value in deserialisedData.ExchangeRates)
            {
                rate.ExchangeRates.Add(new CurrentRate { Rate = value.Rate, Timestamp = value.Timestamp });
            }
```

This is how I did that in an application. Hope this helps a little.

Comment: That would require a lot of manual work, the actual JSON is of course more complex than the simple example in my question

Answer (score 0):

You can check and cast each object in your JSON depending the type of object.
For example consider using [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/) library for JSON parsing, you can do the following:

```
// considering your JSON string
string jsonString = "[{'MyObj':{'Foo':'Bar'}},{'MyObj':[{'Foo':'Bar1'},{'Foo':'Bar2'}]}]";

// parse your JSON into JTokens
var tokens = JToken.Parse(jsonString);

// iterate through  all the tokens
foreach (var token in tokens)
{
   // your token is a grand child
   JToken myObj = token.First.First;

   // check if the grand child is array
   if (myObj is JArray)
   {
      // cast the grand child token into MyObj list or array object
      IEnumerable<MyObj> objList = myObj.ToObject<List<MyObj>>();
      Console.WriteLine("converted to MyObj Array");
   }
   else if (myObj is JObject) // else if its a non array item
   {
       // cast the grand child token into MyObj object
       MyObj obj = myObj.ToObject<MyObj>();
       Console.WriteLine("converted to MyObj");
    }
}

// your MyObj Type will look like this:
public class MyObj 
{
   public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That's basically what the generated converter class does that I mentioned (and now included for completeness) in my question. Also note that your example is not correct, it's the Foo property on the MyObj class that has the issue

Comment: @Hanno how is the Foo property which is changing? I think it's MyObj which is changing it's type. I just saw your converter class which does the same since you updated your question.